# Polymorphic functions in Go supporting native types

Tags: go

I would like to implement a polymorphic function in go. I have a local object `Foo` used in my project that has a `Data() []byte` method. But the original `Foo` object isn't available at all frames in the call stack so sometimes I have the original object available and sometimes I just have a []byte and sometimes, it's being passed represented as a string.

I would like to have a function like `ObjectSatisfiesCondition(obj myInterface) bool` that can be called from any of my existing frames without a major refactor and without reflection.

So I would like to be able to call `ObjectSatisfiesCondition` with either a string, []byte or the original Foo (but actually passing some value that satisfies myInterface)

So I would like to do something like this:

```
type myInterface interface {
    String() string
}

func (s string) String() string {
    return s
}

func (f Foo) String() string {
    return string(f.Data())
}

func (b []byte) String() string {
    return string(b)
}

// Call like: ObjectSatisfiesCondition(foo); ObjectSatisfiesCondition(foo.Data()), ObjectSatisfiesCondition(string(foo.Data()))
```

However I get `cannot define new methods on non-local type string`.

How do I accomplish what I want so that I don't need to write 3 different versions of my function for each type I want to support?

Comment: [This proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45380) (proposal: spec: generics: type switch on parametric types) seems to solve this problem. With it, you could use generics and a type switch without the runtime overhead of reflection.

Comment: Actually my comment should say, "[...] without the runtime overhead of interfaces" since standard library `reflect` is much slower than type asserting. Type assertions require boxing values in interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

The Go type system will not allow you to add methods to basic types. You can use derived types:

```
type FooString string

func (f FooString) String() string {return string(f)}

type FooByteSlice []byte

func (f FooByteSlice) String() string {return string(f)}
```

This way you can simply send a correctly-typed copy of the underlying object to your function:

```
ObjectSatisfiesCondition(FooByteSlice(bSlice))
```

or

```
ObjectStaisfiesCondition(FooString(str))
```

You can also write an adapter like this:

```
func ToMyIntf(in any) myInterface {
  switch k:=in.(type) {
    case myInterface:
         return k
    case string:
         return FooString(k)
    case []byte:
         return FooByteSlice(k)
    default:
         panic(...)
  }
}
```

which enables:

```
ObjectSatisfiesCondition(ToMyIntf(thing))
```

Comment: Another option are generics, but it just shifts the problem somewhere else

Comment: So that does fix the string issue, but then I would have to go and refactor all calls that only have a string type to explicitly cast to FooString right?

Comment: Yes, or write another version of the target function that accepts any, and passed it through ToMyIntf before calling the target function

Comment: The original question says "without reflection". The former avoids reflection, but not the latter. Any solution using `any` is going to require reflection.

Comment: @TylerKropp, no. Type switch is not refkection.

Comment: @BurakSerdar You're right, standard library `reflect` is much different. I see type assertions as reflection conceptually. But maybe OP meant the standard library `reflect`. Performance of type assert is much better than `reflect`.

Comment: @TylerKropp, I agree. I would like to think there is a fine line between type assertion and reflection. Both use runtime type information, but one is a core language feature while the other is a method for discovering type info.

Comment: Op was referring to `reflect` package. I keep forgetting about type assertions